# OS X: How do I use the tmux prefix correctly?

Tags: tmux

I am following [a tmux tutorial](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tmux-crash-course) which states `(Control + b) + %` should open a new pane. When I try to do this from tmux though, the `Control + b` keypress just gets converted into a character which displays on the command line.

Various tmux tutorials seem to treat `Control + b` as a special keypress, but it always just appears as a character on my command line. How do I use the tmux prefix correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That tutorial you linked to in your question has you overriding the default `Control-b` with `Control-a`

try `(Control-a) + %`

this is a popular override.  I use it.  My ~/.tmux.conf has:

```
set -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b
bind C-a send-prefix
```

this is nice when you also remap your caps lock key to be control, the caps lock key and the 'a' key are right next to each other